# Determine week number from date over several years

Tags: r, date, cycle

I'm looking for a way to determine the week number (week beginning on Monday) over several years. That means I don't want to have 0-53 but if, let's say I have 2 years of dates, I want them to be numbered with 0-106 in R.

I tried `strftime(Datum, format ="%W")` but then I only get the annual week number and not as a whole.

Comment: you could factorize the years in your data and then do:          `as.numeric(levels(year))[year]*strftime(Datum, format ="%W")`, where "year" is the factorized years vector / column.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right, but that doesn't help me, since I will have at some point (2 for year 1997, 3 for week 3, 2*3=6) and at some point (1 for year 1996, 6 for week 6, 1*6=6).

Comment: add a reproducible example and an image of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Given that you did not provide any data, I took the liberty of creating some:

```
#create data
Datum<-c("2013-03-01", "2014-06-02", "2013-06-01")
# format data to year-month-day with strptime
Datum<-strptime(Datum, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

You now need to identify the origin year. As I'm sure you are aware not all years have the same number of weeks 52.29 in a leap year vs. 52.4 in a standard calendar year but as this is unlikely to be a consideration for only 2 years we can use the number of weeks returned through the strftime function.

```
origin.year=as.numeric(min(substring(Datum,1,4)))
# number of weeks in first year (offset for second year)
n.weeks<-52
```

Now we can create a vector containing the number of weeks to offset each week in Datum (X).

```
X<-as.numeric(substring(Datum,1,4)!=origin.year)*n.weeks
```

We can then simply add this vector to the number of weeks returned by strftime when it is applied to Datum

```
    week.vec<-as.numeric(strftime(Datum, "%W"))+X
```

This will work for 2 years, but if you have more years than this, you will need to modify the offsets to account for this.

Comment: Thank you so far, I'll try it out. Yeah, sorry for the lack of data given. I have 20 years of historical stock data, download here: [link](http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=VOW.DE&a=02&b=24&c=1995&d=11&e=9&f=2015&g=d&ignore=.csv)

Comment: Things get a little trickier with a time series of this length, as you will have to account for that fraction of a week. Have you considered working with days since origin? The code for this is much easier.